# Create a hash that could be validated only in the next 5 minutes

Tags: php, security, hash

I want to make an algorithm in which we can create a hash based on a `string` that could be validated only in the next 5 minutes!

So we have 3 methods for our class:

**make**: which is gonna make the hash based on the `string` and also considering current `time`, so it could be validated using our own `validate` method only in the next 5 minutes.

**validate**: we receive a `string` and also a `hash` value, we check if the `hash` is based on the `string` made in the previous **5 minutes**.

**magic_happens_here**: sorry but I really can't come up with a solution for this, already googled. here is our code to generate a `hash` based on a `string` and also considering current time, but in a float way!?

```
<?php

namespace App\Secure;

class timeHash
{

    public static function make ($str)
    {
        return static::magic_happens_here($str);
    }

    public static function validate ($str, $hash)
    {
        return $this->magic_happens_here($str) == $hash;
    }

    public static function magic_happens_here ($str)
    {
        //!
    }

}
```

is this even possible!!? I can't think of a way of doing it!

of course we can use `timestamp` and calculate all the possible values of 5 minutes ago and compare it to the provided hash, but that doesn't make any sense; isn't there any other solutions?

Comment: What do you mean by "validated in the next 5 minutes"?  Do you mean you want to generate a temporary hash that will only be considered valid for the 5 minutes since it was created then cease to be valid, or do you mean that you want to create a hash, but not have it considered valid until 5 minutes after its creation?

Comment: first thing you mentioned, "generate a temporary hash `of a string` that will only be considered valid for the 5 minutes since it was created", so in the next 5 minutes, magic_hash($str) == $hash is true, but after 5 minutes it's false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply include the timestamp as readable value in your hash, *and* include it in the hash so you can verify its authenticity. You should use an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) for that purpose.

```
                          hash
                    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
$hash = '1234567890:abcdef1234567890'
         ^^^^^^^^^^
         timestamp
```

```
$time = time();
$hash = "$time:" . hash_hmac('sha256', $time, $secretKey);
```

What you use as the data for hashing (here: just the timestamp) and the `$secretKey` depends on what data exactly you're trying to proof. To validate you can easily strip the timestamp from the hash, verify that it's within 5 minutes of now, and repeat the same hash operation to confirm the hash value.

Remember: without a secret key, anyone would obviously be able to fabricate such a hash. The secret key is something only *you* know, and which proves that *you* had originally created the hash.

You may also look into [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) for much the same purpose.

Comment: smart way of doing this, and really does the job, but isn't there any other way so we can think of the output string as a whole and the time could be also hidden? I don't want users see the time() in the begining

Comment: A hash is by definition irreversible, you cannot hide the timestamp in the hash itself, it must be in a reversible format. You could obscure it by base 64 encoding the result (much like JSON Web Tokens do), or you *encrypt* the value with a secret. The timestamp being shown just means the user could validate themselves the validity of the token; other than that it shouldn't give them any leverage.

Comment: Though alternatively you can rotate your `$secretKey` every 5 minutes, which obviously invalidates old hashes automatically. Though it does so in 5 minute windows, not 5 minutes from the creation time of the hash; for that you'd have to keep the last X secret keys around and try them all.

Comment: you are 100% right, I know there is no security breach in this, but my case is a little bit more complicated and I prefer not to show the time() in the beginning, can we make it an encryption and do this? thank you for the helps

Comment: Whenever I hear "my case is more complicated" I'd stop to ask why. Can you *really* not employ techniques that the world's largest and most secure organisations can…? Perhaps you need something completely different to begin with?

Comment: What happens when the clocks are not synchronized, like when powering up some Android phones without a SIM card. I think this fellow needs a discussion of a protocol.

Comment: @jww It's all happening on the server, so it only needs to be in sync with itself. If you have multiple servers, put ntp on all of them. It's entirely within your control.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this issue by thinking that your data blob (the hash) needs to have a state ("active" / "expired" or similar).

If the state is bound directly to the timestamp, and you don't provide that timestamp outside of the hash, nobody can change the state. That is because the hash is irreversible. So as a conclusion, you need to store the timestamp somewhere to be able to change the state.

If you don't want to show the timestamp to the receiver, you have two options:

1. Encrypt it so that only you have the encryption key
2. Do not send the timestamp to the receiver at all - only send the hash. Keep the timestamp & hash pair table stored on the server.

Now for me it looks easy to pick one of these options: If your server is stateless go for the option 1. On the other hand if your server is not stateless and you have a database or other ways to persist data, go for the option 2.

In any case include the timestamp in your hash together with the string you are hashing to have the authenticity of the data and also use HMAC. I would also consider salting the hash with a random value.

Finally in your validation function on the server, check from your record that the timestamp paired with the received hash is no older than 5 minutes and validate the hash.

Answer (score 1):

For me this sounds like you actually want to create kind of a token, which can be used like a ticket for a certain time.

If you need the application to be stateless (no database possible), then @deceze answer is the way to go, the timestamp must be retrievable from the hash-string, but must also be used as input parameter to the HMAC function.

If your application can access a database, you can solve the problem in a more safe way. In this case you can create a random token and store its hash together with the creation timestamp in the database. The token itself will be sent plaintext to the user.

The advantage is, that even if an attacker gains privileges on the server he cannot do anything with the tokens. There is no hidden key to produce new valid tokens, and they contain no information themselfes, only random characters.

Comment: I don't want to access db

Answer (score -1):

You could add a number to the string that presents the current time in 5min steps.

5=1 | 10=2 | 15=3....

18:15 = "183"
13:45 = "139"

You should also add the date.

This would give you a 5min time Frame to validate the Hash but the start of that frame is defined by time and not by the generation of the Hash.

I think there should be a better way to do it.

Comment: You have your String "Hello World!" 
then you generate the Integer that represents the current time but not the exact time. It's 11:15 then you start to gemerate the Hash.

Instead of Hashing "Hello World!" you Hash "Hello World!_113"

Comment: has nothing to do with my problem, then in the back-end, how I can figure out if the hash is made in the previous 5 minutes?